# Lubuntu 18.04 can't start steam

Tags: lubuntu, steam

Lubuntu 18.04 for some reason steam uninstalled it self I couldn't run it with command: steam

Re-installed it with `sudo apt-get install steam`, and it worked, logged in and all of the games that were installed previously were showing as not installed.

For some reason I thought its good idea to delete the folder manually of steam and reinstall it again, went in .local/share and deleted .steam it was about 50 Gbs, next thing I did `sudo apt-get remove steam` and then `sudo apt-get install steam`.
Now this is the error I get:

```
pc@PC:~$ steam
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
xz: (stdin): File format not recognized
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
find: ‘/home/pc/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime’: No such file or directory
```

Thanks for taking the time to read.

Comment: Could you try `sudo apt purge steam` and then `sudo apt install steam`, this should delete all files related to steam and then reinstall them, whereas `sudo apt remove` does not.

Answer (score 0):

Running this command solved the issue;
mkdir /home/$USER/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime